# NinjectWebCommon bindings not loading from subdirectories

Tags: c#, ninject

I have an MVC project that loads plugins from a configured folder using ninject. It has been working just fine for months, but the project requirements have changed. The plugins now need to be in separate folders to allow easier clean-up of dependent libraries or other files.

This code is inside NinjectWebCommon:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins");

    kernel.Bind(a => a.FromAssembliesInPath(path)
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .InheritedFrom<IPlugin>()
        .BindToSelf()
        .Configure(b => b.InRequestScope()));
}
```

Is there a change I could make to the Bind call to make it include sub-directories? Obviously, I could loop thru all the sub-directories myself and call bind on each one, but that seemed messy to me.

EDIT: I should add that it does something odd with all the plugins inside sub-folders. It seems to load the plugin inside the first folder that it finds and then stops.

EPILOGUE: What I ended up doing was based off of Battery's answer, but it was a little different - thought I would share.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    string pluginDirectory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins");

    IEnumerable<string> pluginAssemblies = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pluginDirectory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    kernel.Bind(a => a.From(pluginAssemblies)
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .InheritedFrom<IPlugin>()
        .BindToSelf()
        .Configure(b => b.InRequestScope()));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that some plugins are loaded from the sub folders? Because based on the [source code](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/0a918f542c616c34590d29b4a380930e1e30bad3/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingBuilder/AssemblyFinder.cs#L71-L74) the `FromAssembliesInPath` is only looking for dlls in the given directory and it does not go into the sub folders. Currently this cannot be easily changed so you would need to foreach over the sub-directories and call the `FromAssembliesInPath` on them manually.

Comment: @nemesv Originally, that was my plan. I looped over each directory inside the plugin directory and called bind there. But it seemed messy, so I was looking for a neater solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ninject does not support searching sub directories.

However, there's also the more generic overloads which you can easily make use of:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.From(IEnumerable<Assembly>));
```

and

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.From(IEnumerable<string>)); //assembly paths
```

so there's no need to do:

```
foreach(var assembly in GetAssemblies())
{
    kernel.Bind(a => a.From(assembly))
          .XYZ;
}
```

but instead you would rather do:

```
kernel.Bind(a => a.From(GetAssemblies())
     .XYZ;
```

Where `GetAssemblies` contains the necessary IO access to find all the DLLs to load...

Comment: I actually couldn't just call GetAssemblies, but I did use the gist of your answer to solve my problem. I will add a edit to show what I did. Thanks!